# Turn off "user must change password at next logon" checkbox by default when creating new user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

On Windows Server 2008, when you add a new user (manually, i.e. using *Server Manager* > *Roles* > *Active Directory Domain Services* > *Active Directory Users and Computers* > [site name] > right-click on Users and choose "*New*" > "*User*"), the password window has the "User must change password at next logon" checkbox marked by default. I want it to be **off** by default. Is there any way to achieve this?

Note that I do NOT want a script or what-have-you that will batch update existing users. I want to change the default for adding *new* users. I am also totally uninterested in any lectures about password security: that setting simply must be turned off for these users, and that's that.

Comment: But, but... security and accountability... Is a user creation script out of the question as well?

Comment: @Athom, We will eventually need a user creation script, but we also sometimes need to add a single user, and would prefer not to have to use a script for that. (If it makes you feel any better, these passwords are assigned to the users, and the users are fully aware that they're not private.)

Comment: I worry just as much for the IT person who knows the passwords for their legal accountability... Either way, sometimes you can't do what is ideal for whatever reason. As for your question, my understanding is the Windows / AD API enables it by default on most types of creation and then must be undone. I also do not believe you can alter ADUC /DSA defaults for user creations unless (been a while since tried) you set a "copy" account that way. But I think it will still check the box.

Comment: @paradroid: you may be right, but serverfault scares me. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that. All you can do is try to "copy" an existing user, maybe it will inherit the setting.